# Is there way to colorize by RGB in GIMP?

Tags: color, gimp

There is a `colorize` tool in GIMP but it only provides `HSV`. Most of time I want to colorize with `RGB` so I'm using [RapidTables' RGB to HSV color conversion](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hsv.htm).

Is there way to colorize with RGB only?

Comment: Thanks for your info! Is there someone who can move the question? I don't have privilege for it.

Comment: I have flagged this question for moderator attention. They will decide if this question will be moved or not.

Comment: If there is an accepted answer then there is no reason to migrate unless your comments are from photo.stack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inbuilt *Colorize Tool* from Gimp is hardcoded to only allow only colorization by hue, saturation, and lightness. There is no colorize tool which allows setting color exactly by RGB values.

Still, it is very easy to colorize a greyscale image using the **Bucket Fill** tool where we can define any foreground color not only by HSV but also using RGB, a HTML color noration, the colour wheel, or the color picker tool.

In addition, we are able to adjust the opacity of the colorize effect, and we do have several fill mode options:

- Bucket fill mode **Addition** (foreground fill to RGB 255,0,0, opacitiy 100):

  [image]
- Bucket fill mode **Color** (foreground fill to RGB 255,0,0, opacity 100):

  [image]

Because bucket fill is so easy to configure and use I never missed another colorize tool.

Depending on your needs you may also find a plugin to add more sophisticated colorize tools (e.g. colorizing with more than one color in the G'Mic tools)

Answer (score 0):

A third method is to use *Color>Map>Gradient map* on a Grayscale version. The simpler method uses a two-colors gradient (black to color, or color to white). Better results are obtained with a three-color gradient: black-to-color-to-white.