# Converting a logo to monotone in GIMP

Tags: gimp, tools, color-spaces, grayscale

I usually convert my logos to a particular colour (not just greyscale) in photoshop by using the following process: Convert to Greyscale/Choose Duotone/Select colour and click okay.

[image: photoshop screenshot]

**I need to do the same thing in GIMP** but can't find duotone/monotone options. I need a method of being able to do this conversion quickly and without having to select each part of the logo and the paint brush.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: This? http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21780/is-there-way-to-colorize-by-rgb-in-gimp

Answer (score 1):

If the logo is still on its own transparent layer, at least two ways:

#### Alpha lock:

1. select the layer, and set alpha-lock (checkerboard icon at top of the layers list)
2. bucket-fill with required color (or apply whatever paint tools you fancy, such a Blend). The alpha-lock will preserve the opacity lever of all pixels.

#### Reusing the selection:

1. Select the layer and *Layer>Transparency>Alpha to selection*
2. Add a new transparent layer, and hide the original logo layer
3. Bucket-fill the selection (or Blend, etc....)

Comment: Nice solution. Works well for converting the whole logo with the 'Fill whole selection' option of the Bucket-Fill tool.